# Exporting CSV file from python sqlite3

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

I've been trying to google this for hours now, sorry if the answer is already out there

This is what I have so far:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
table = c.fetchall()
print(table)

#to export as csv file
with open("wub.csv", "wb") as write_file:
     cursor = connection.cursor()
          for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table"):
          write_file.write(row)
```

But I keep getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rachel/Documents/database.py", line 52, in <module>
    write_file.write(row)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
```

so I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything wrong -how would I properly export the table to an external CSV file? Thank you

EDIT:
[to Janekmuric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H926m.png)

Comment: Does `write_file.write(",".join(row))` fix it? Maybe `write_file.write(",".join(row) + "\n")` in case it doesn't add a newline automatically. Anyway, as @cricket_007's link suggests, there's also a module for handling csv files

Comment: Warning: if you are using Python3, and still want to write the .cvs file in binary mode, you'll have to encode the strings returned from the sqlite cursor to bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below will iterate over a list of tuples that `SELECT` (`execute`) returns.

```
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table"):
      write_file.write(row)
```

Eg.
If you have a database with rows `number`, `word`, `colour` your code will loop over something like this:

```
(23, "tree", "red")
(17, "code", "green")
(11, "python", "yellow")
```

And what you're trying to do is write a **tuple** to a file. You can only write strings (or `bytes`) to a file.

What you have to do is convert that tuple to a string. For this you can use the `join()` function.

Your code will now look like this:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
table = c.fetchall()
print(table)

#to export as csv file
with open("wub.csv", "wb") as write_file:
     cursor = connection.cursor()
     for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table"):
          writeRow = " ".join(row)
          write_file.write(writeRow)
```

`" ".join(row)` will join all tuple elements and seperate them with, in this case, a space.

---

There are a few problems with this.

Join only works with lists and tuples that contain string elements only (so the code   above wouldn't work if your database had a `REAL` or `INTEGER` type)

You can just write a loop that goes over each element in the list and converts it to a string.

I also added a `.encode()` because you are opening your CSV file with `"rb"` so you need to convert it to `bytes` before writing to the file.

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
table = c.fetchall()
print(table)

#to export as csv file
with open("wub.csv", "wb") as write_file:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table"):
        writeRow = " ".join([str(i) for i in row])
        write_file.write(writeRow.encode())
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply -this worked, but my table has more than one 'type of field' (not really sure how to describe it), and the CSV file has all the data into one field (i'll edit in a screenshot into the question part) -is there a way to get it so that one table field is assigned one excel field, and each entry is on a different row?

Comment: @Rachel I'm not sure what you're asking. It would be nice if you could upload the entire code and add more details about what you need. You could also mark this answer as accepted and post a new question.

Comment: Why are you using a "wb" flag in open( ) ? it is a text file...

Answer (score 12):

```
import sqlite3
import csv

inpsql3 = sqlite3.connect('input.sql3')
sql3_cursor = inpsql3.cursor()
sql3_cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM clients')
with open('output.csv','w') as out_csv_file:
  csv_out = csv.writer(out_csv_file)
  # write header                        
  csv_out.writerow([d[0] for d in sql3_cursor.description])
  # write data                          
  for result in sql3_cursor:
    csv_out.writerow(result)
inpsql3.close()
```

Note the use of `description` member of the sql cursor to get the names of the headers in the `clients` table.

You can, of course, modify the names of the input and output files.  And you can also modify the parameters of the `csv.writer`.

The original author had the flag 'wb' for writing bytes; however we are not writing bytes.